# Writing file in a CPU-intensive program in Java

Tags: java, file-io

I'm writing a Java program that performs a few millions of unit computation. Each unit would take around 1 sec, so overall it would take a few days to finish. After computing each unit, I want to write some results (a few lines of text) into a file. Since writing files takes time, I wonder whether I should create a separate thread for writing files, so it wouldn't block the main computation.

Thank you.

Comment: Too broad, too little details...

Comment: You have have measured the time it takes a modern computer to write a few lines of text to a file and compared that to the massive computation that you are doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are running on mainstream OS, not exotic one.  If you just write to `FileOutputStream` and do not do `flush()` on it, the data will most probably be written into memory buffer, which takes virtually no time.  Real write on disk will happen later asynchronously, so don't mind.

Comment: What if I use flush()? The program takes a few days to run, so I'd like to make sure that the partial results are indeed saved to disk in case the machine crashes. How often would the file writer flushes if I do not explicitly call flush()?

Comment: What class are we talking about?

Comment: I'm using FileWriter right now.

Comment: Oh, you are using FileWiter.  I'm afraid FileWriter does buffering itself which is bad in your case.  If using FileOutputStream directly is not an option, you better call `flush()` after each unit.  If there is only about one unit per second, overhead will not be very little.

Answer (score 1):

Writing files takes practically no time at all. Unlike when reading, the thread doing the writing doesn't have to wait for the actual disk I/O operations to complete.

Comment: Thanks. What about flush()?

Comment: For most classes, `flush` still doesn't wait for the actual disk I/O to complete. It just flushes the application buffer. "*If the intended destination of this stream is an abstraction provided by the underlying operating system, for example a file, then flushing the stream guarantees only that bytes previously written to the stream are passed to the operating system for writing; it does not guarantee that they are actually written to a physical device such as a disk drive.*" -- [OutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

Unless the size of the write is massive, then just write it to disk while after you calculate each unit, inline and worry about threading later, maybe after you actually know that your spending a measurable percentage of time writing to disk rather than doing your computation.

But if you really have to do it in another thread, use a fixed sized executor:

```
// somewhere during initialisation 
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);


// after each unit

final Unit unit = null; // your stuff
threadPool.submit( new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    try ( FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(yourFileHere, true) ){
      fos.write( unit.toBytes() );
    } catch ( IOException e) {
      // guess you need to handle this ??
    }
  }
});


// do make sure that when you finish you call
// to wait for tasks to finish
threadPool.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [Java Logging API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html) or some logging framework such as [Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/).

Just before your thread ends, it can write some information into a logging file. It is thread safe and takes practically no time at all.

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 adds asynchronous IO so you could use those APIs to decouple your computation and results saving tasks, but as others have pointed out that's probably overkill given the amount of disk IO you seem to require.